# MS excel time format issue

Tags: excel

I have time in the format hh:mm:ss.00 which I want to copy to three different columns as hh in one column, mm in second and ss.00 in third. I use text to columns for this. Excel, however, makes it ss in the third column instead of ss.00. Decimal points are important for me. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hours:  `=TEXT(A1,"hh")`

Minutes:  `=RIGHT(TEXT(A1,"hh:mm"),2)`

Seconds:  `=TEXT(A1,"ss.00")`

Could you please try this

Comment: Hi Shiva, I just noticed that whenever my seconds are more than 59.51, the formulas you gave rounds off the minutes. eg. 21:54:59.65 become 21, 55, 59.65. This went unnoticed since my data is huge. Is there a way to fix this? I want my hh mm ss.00 as it is, without any change. It affects my calculations. Thanks

Comment: @Aqua Can you try this for minutes,  `=MID(TEXT(A1,"hh:mm:ss.00"),4,2)`

Answer (score 1):

If formulas are okay with you, this is the way to go:

For hours:

```
=HOUR(A1)
```

For minutes:

```
=MINUTE(A1)
```

For seconds with milliseconds:

```
=TEXT(A1,"ss.000")*1
```

If you have formatting issues, you should select column and press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `1`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Hour and minutes are fine, but when I apply your formula for the seconds, it gives me 00:00:00.00

Comment: Select that column and press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `1`

Comment: Thanks for your reply zipa. I tried ctrl+shift+1. It does return the seconds in ss.00 format but some of the values are not same as the original time. e.g. 16:51:55.70 becomes 56.70.